# Не могу импортировать некоторые пакеты JavaCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, gradle, javacv

Я хочу сделать приложение с распознаванием лица, опираясь на этот [пример](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/OpenCVFaceRecognizer.java). Использую я JavaCV 1.5.8, но ничего не получается из-за проблем с данными импортами:

```java
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.BytePointer;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.IntPointer;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.DoublePointer;

import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_core.*;
import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_face.*;
import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_imgcodecs.*;
```

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'BytePointer'
Cannot resolve symbol 'IntPointer'
Cannot resolve symbol 'DoublePointer'
Cannot resolve symbol 'opencv_core'
Cannot resolve symbol 'opencv_face'
Cannot resolve symbol 'opencv_imgcodecs'
```

Раз у меня ничего не получилось со старым примером, то я решил глянуть на то, как актуально подключать JavaCV и обратил внимание [сюда](https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp/blob/master/samples/javacv-demo/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/samples/Demo.java). Здесь уже используется gradle-javacpp. Я подключил плагин, добавил зависимости, скопировал полностью импорты, но всё равно проблема. На этот раз со следующими пакетами:

```java
import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_core.*;
import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_calib3d.*;
import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_objdetect.*;
```

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'opencv_core'
Cannot resolve symbol 'opencv_imgproc'
Cannot resolve symbol 'opencv_calib3d'
Cannot resolve symbol 'opencv_objdetect'
```

Также у меня не отображаются пакеты внутри org.bytedeco.opencv

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'opencv'
```

И, по сути, с этими импортами тоже проблема

```java
import org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.*;
import org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_imgproc.*;
import org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_calib3d.*;
import org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_objdetect.*;
```

Я пытался создать проект на основе примеров, использующих javacv 1.4.x, искал ответы на похожие проблемы, всячески менял подключаемые зависимости, чистил проект, пытался что-то сделать с помощью gradle-javacpp, использовал рекомендации авторов библиотеки по подключению зависимостей и работе с ними, но ничего не получается. Может кто знает, в чем проблема?

Мой top-level `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`app/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.bytedeco.gradle-javacpp-platform' version '1.5.8'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.findyourselfinthephoto"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        //coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/**/**.json'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/*.json'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/**'
        //pickFirst 'nd4j-native.properties'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.github.martipello:MultiImageView:1.0.8.2' //MultiImageView(PhotoCollage)

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0' //get-requests
    implementation 'com.sezinkarli:random-user-agent-generator:1.3' //random user-agent

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //implementation project(path: ':OpenCVLibrary')

    implementation 'com.github.onimur:handle-path-oz:1.0.7' //handle real path

    implementation 'org.bytedeco:javacv-platform:1.5.8'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco:opencv-platform:4.6.0-1.5.8'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco:opencv-platform-gpu:4.6.0-1.5.8'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco:ffmpeg-platform:5.1.2-1.5.8'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco:ffmpeg-platform-gpl:5.1.2-1.5.8'
}
```

`settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'} //for MultiImageView
    }
}
rootProject.name = "FindYourselfInThePhoto"
include ':app'
//include ':OpenCVLibrary'
```

Comment: зачем  вы используете warpper  JavaCV ?  Почему не используете нативный  opencv?  у  вас   требование  использовать javaCV?  Если  у вас   проблема с настройкой  opencv  в java  намекните

Comment: @Труфальдино, да, было требование использовать его

Comment: Импортировать можно только то что находится в наличии.

Comment: не очень понимаю  проблему.   Создаем проект в  eclipse/  делаем этот  прпроект  maven  проектом ,   добавлем  в pom.xml   dependies (  просто копируем в pom.xml  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv-platform</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0-1.5.8</version>
    </dependency> ) все рабтает..  или я что-то  упустил?

Comment: @Труфальдино, нет, ничего не упустили. Просто странно, что в gradle не работает, а в Maven всё хорошо. Но спасибо!

Comment: Я не уверен, но  у  меня  в Android Studion я через  gradle тоже все устновил.   просто    с исмпортировать  jar  ники ил и в проект или системный Library_path

Comment: @Труфальдино, через внешние библиотеки у меня тоже работало, но вот хотелось через зависимости сделать

Comment: Очень похоже что вы как-то не так Андроид зависимости подключаете. Вот есть старый официальный пример: https://github.com/bytedeco/sample-projects/blob/master/javacv-android-recognize/app/build.gradle

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja да, я видел его, но с того момента у них изменились методы подключения: `org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets` теперь больше не используется, там нужно подключать следующим образом `implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: moduleName + '-platform', version: moduleVersion + '-1.5.8'`. Я и как в примере подключал, но тоже не работали некоторые импорты, хотя 1 в 1 копировал

Comment: @EugeneKrivenj Я подключал зависимости и как я описал выше - оно тоже не работало. Я и чистый проект делал, но тоже ничего не работало

Comment: Вот есть пример посвежее, там все иначе подключается https://github.com/bytedeco/sample-projects/blob/master/JavaCV-android-example/app/build.gradle

Comment: И не копируйте примеры для JVM слепо в Андроид, структура пакетов может отличаться.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja всё еще ничего. Нет ли возможности у Вас проверить зависимости через gradle?

Comment: Опубликуйте в публичном репозитории минимальный проект с проблемой, я смогу тогда посмотреть и по возможности исправить.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja https://github.com/Tamada4a/JavaCVTest
В WithJavacppExtract я реализовал пример - https://github.com/bytedeco/sample-projects/blob/master/JavaCV-android-example/app/build.gradle

В ImplementationsAndPlugin - простое подключение зависимостей с использованием их плагина

Comment: Реализовал, но не точно :) Поэтому и не работало.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja спасибо!

Comment: @Труфальдино, у Вас нет случайно опыта в собирании OpenCV под Android?

Comment: из источников? Вы хотите собрать  чистый  openCv  или   дополнительными пакетами? В  чем проблема?

Comment: @Труфальдино Да, мне нужно собрать OpenCV из источников с доп.пакетами, но я не могу найти подходящей конфигурации: какая java, какое sdk и через что собирать. Был бы очень сильно благодарен за Вашу помощь

Comment: @Труфальдино У меня следующая конфигурация: Java: 1.8.0_202, SDK tools 25, SDK platform-tools 25, NDK: r21e. По итогу  получаю следующую ошибку: BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\volce\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\volce\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:655: null returned: -1073741819

Comment: Мой cmake: https://pastebin.com/N2RYPVPz

Comment: OpenCV и opencv_contrib версии 4.6.0

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/FhwXknM0fwnIiA  там со всем хламом  и openBlas и gmeedia  и еще  много всего  терпения короче   нужно побольше

Comment: @Труфальдино Какие-то зависимости нужны? Или что-то в PATH /системных переменных прописывать?

Comment: ничего не надо кроме  gcc (MInGV в случае виндовс) и java .Все должно быть  указано в Path

Comment: @Труфальдино он не находит ни eigen, ни остальные доп.библиотеки

Comment: Что еще  добавить ?  я добавлю

Comment: @Труфальдино, если Вы про библиотеки: gstreamer, openexr, openblas, eigen, tesseract - ни одну из них он не видит
А если Вы про модули определенные из opencv_contrib - то там все нужны

Comment: Че то какая-то. Еще раз последовательность действий.  1.  Устанавливаем git 2. устанавливаем mingw  или любой другой  С компилятор 3. Устанавилваем Смаке. 4. создаем папку  lib  5.  копируем наш  файл  в папку  lib 6.  в командной строке  вызваем на исполенение наш  файл. 7ждем . Все переменные  должны  быть  указаны  в PATH

Comment: я  могу  выложить то  что  у меня накомпилиловалось  но это  5 ГБ!

Comment: @Труфальдино я был бы очень благодарен за это! Потому что я какой день бьюсь с этим, но у меня ничего не получается

Comment: есть куда выложить ю у меня уже везде под завязку

Comment: У меня получилось!!!!!

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В проекте `WithJavacppExtract`
https://github.com/Tamada4a/JavaCVTest

подключите зависимости как в примере
https://github.com/bytedeco/sample-projects/blob/master/JavaCV-android-example/app/build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.5.8'
javacpp  group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'openblas-platform', version: '0.3.21-1.5.8'
javacpp  group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'opencv-platform', version: '4.6.0-1.5.8'
javacpp  group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'ffmpeg-platform', version: '5.1.2-1.5.8'
```

и все прекрасно импортируется

Answer (score -2):

Вот мой pom.xml для  проекта openCvTest

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>OpenCvTest</groupId>
      <artifactId>OpenCvTest</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv-platform</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.0-1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

а вот мой  java class

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.indexer.*;
import org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.*;
import org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_imgproc.*;
import org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_calib3d.*;
import org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_objdetect.*;
import org.opencv.core.Core;

import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_core.*;
import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_calib3d.*;
import static org.bytedeco.opencv.global.opencv_objdetect.*;

    public class Demo {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          System.out.println(Core.VERSION);
          System.out.println(org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.getPlatform());
        }
    }
```

нет проблем

Comment: Автор вообще-то в Андроид это все дело пытается встроить. А вы ему про Maven и JVM рассказываете.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, Вы прочитали мои комментарии? То что  вы не  видите в ответе,  значит  что в вопросе не было  указано  "для андроид"..

Comment: Указано! Меткой `android`