# Как собрать OpenCV 4.6.0 с opencv_contrib под Android на Windows

Tags: android, opencv, cmake

Мне нужно собрать OpenCV с доп.модулями под Android на Windows. Я делаю всё по [этому](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7CiuWyLkr8&ab_channel=YaseenKhan) гайду, но у меня не конфигурируется билд

Мой cmake:

```
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=c:/ninja/ninja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=E:/OpenCV-android -DANDROID_PROJECTS_BUILD_TYPE="ANT" -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_JAVA=ON -DBUILD_opencv_java=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB=ON -DBUILD_PYTHON=OFF -DINSTALL_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF -DANDROID_EXAMPLES_WITH_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DWITH_OPENCL=ON -DANDROID_NDK_HOST_X64=ON  -DANDROID_NDK=C:/Users/volce/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r25b/   -DANDROID_SDK=C:/Users/volce/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/volce/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r25b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DANDROID_STL=c++_static -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_ABI=x86_64 -DANDROID_ABI=x86 -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_NDK_HOST_X64=ON -D BUILD_opencv_python3=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF  -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=C:/OpenCV/opencv_contrib/modules -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=25 -DANDROID_SDK_TARGET=30  ..
```

Мои системные переменные:
[image: Системные переменные]

Переменные в PATH:

[image: Переменные в PATH]

Использую я `Java 19`

[Вывод из консоли](https://pastebin.com/r62VB1V7)

[CMakeError.log](https://pastebin.com/yDFiKYcB)

[CMakeOutput.log](https://pastebin.com/NVk7KPbi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашёл два варианта:

1. **shell скрипт** (взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1464972/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-javacv#comment2629052_1464972))

- Устанавливаем [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) и прописываем в `PATH`  (`C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`)
- Устанавливаем [Cmake](https://cmake.org/download/) 3.24.3 и прописываем в `PATH` (`C:\Program Files\CMake\bin`)
- Устанавливаем [java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/) и прописываем в `PATH` (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin`), создаем переменную `JAVA_HOME`(`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202`)
- Устанавливаем C компилятор ([mingw](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/downloads/68260/mingw-get-setup.exe/) или [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/) и тп). Если вы будете использовать `mingw`, то в нём нужно будет установить: `mingw32-base-bin`,
  `mingw32-gcc-fortran-bin`,
  `mingw32-gcc-g++-bin`,
  `mingw32-gcc-objc-bin`,
  `msys-base-bin`. А затем в `PATH` добавить `C:\MinGW\bin`
- Также может понадобиться [WSL под Windows](https://blog.altuninvv.ru/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8/49-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-debian-%D0%B2-windows-10-wsl2), но у меня получилось и просто через Git Bash
- Создаём в пустой папке скрипт `build.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -e
myRepo=$(pwd)
CMAKE_GENERATOR_OPTIONS=-G"Visual Studio 17 2022"
#CMAKE_GENERATOR_OPTIONS=-G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
#CMAKE_GENERATOR_OPTIONS=(-G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64)  # CMake 3.14+ is required
if [  ! -d "$myRepo/gstreamer"  ]; then
    echo "cloning gstreamer"
    git clone https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer.git
else
    cd gstreamer
    git pull --rebase
    cd ..
fi
if [  ! -d "$myRepo/openexr"  ]; then
    echo "cloning openexr"
    git clone https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openexr.git
else
    cd openexr
    git pull --rebase
    cd ..
fi
if [  ! -d "$myRepo/openblas"  ]; then
    echo "cloning openblas"
    git clone https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS.git
else
    cd openblas
    git pull --rebase
    cd ..
fi
if [  ! -d "$myRepo/eigen"  ]; then
    echo "cloning eigen"
    git clone https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
else
    cd eigen
    git pull --rebase
    cd ..
fi
if [  ! -d "$myRepo/opencv"  ]; then
    echo "cloning opencv"
    git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
else
    cd opencv
    git pull --rebase
    cd ..
fi
if [  ! -d "$myRepo/opencv_contrib"  ]; then
    echo "cloning opencv_contrib"
    git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
else
    cd opencv_contrib
    git pull --rebase
    cd ..
fi
if [  ! -d "$myRepo/tesseract"  ]; then
    echo "cloning tesseract"
    git clone https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract.git
else
    cd tesseract
    git pull --rebase
    cd ..
fi
RepoSource=opencv
mkdir -p build_opencv
pushd build_opencv
CMAKE_OPTIONS=( -DBUILD_opencv_world:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_JAVA:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF  -DWITH_CUDA:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DINSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON)
set -x
cmake "${CMAKE_GENERATOR_OPTIONS[@]}" "${CMAKE_OPTIONS[@]}" -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH="$myRepo"/opencv_contrib/modules -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$myRepo/install/$RepoSource" "$myRepo/$RepoSource"
echo "************************* $Source_DIR -->debug"
cmake --build .  --config debug
echo "************************* $Source_DIR -->release"
cmake --build .  --config release
cmake --build .  --target install --config release
cmake --build .  --target install --config debug
popd
```

- Открываем Git Bash, открываем в нём папку с нашим скриптом и прописываем `bash build.sh`
- Если у вас ошибка `syntax error: unexpected end of file`, то вот [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6366607/18750563)
- На выходе получаем opencv_java460.dll и opencv-460.jar

2. **cmake с ninja** (взято [отсюда](https://youtu.be/C7CiuWyLkr8), но доработано)

Тут я опишу то, что я использовал для сборки(не факт, что именно это всё нужно или конкретные версии, но на них у меня работало):

- Устанавливаем [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) и прописываем в `PATH` (`C:\Users\volce\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\` и `C:\Users\volce\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\`)
- Устанавливаем [java 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html) и прописываем в `PATH` и `JAVA_HOME` (см. выше)
- Устанавливаем `Cmake 3.24.3` (на другой версии не пробовал) и прописываем в `PATH` (см. выше)
- Скачать [NDK r25](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads), разархивировать и добавить переменную среды `ANDROID_NDK: C:\Users\volce\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\android-ndk-r25b`
- Скачиваем [SDK tools r25.2.3](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip), [platform-tools r25.0.1](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r25.0.1-windows.zip) и [build-tools r25.0.1](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r25.0.1-windows.zip)
- В папке с SDK заменяем содержимое папок `tools`, `build-tools` и `platform-tools` на скачанные
- Также, в PATH я добавил `C:\Users\volce\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools` и `C:\Users\volce\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`
- Добавляем переменные среды: `ANDROID_HOME` и `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, где указываем путь до SDK (например, `C:\Users\volce\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`)
- Скачиваем [ant](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) и прописываем в `PATH` (`C:\apache-ant-1.10.12\bin` и `C:\apache-ant-1.10.12\lib`) и создаём `ANT_HOME` (`C:\apache-ant-1.10.12`)
- Скачиваем `MinGw`, устанавливаем нужные пакеты и прописываем в `PATH` (см. выше)
- Скачиваем `Visual Studio`

Что я делал дальше

- Создал папку под всё это дело
- В ней делаем `git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git` и `git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git`
- В папке с `opencv` переходим в `samples\android` и в файле `CMakeLists.txt` удаляем `add_subdirectory(15-puzzle)` (из-за этого у меня не собиралось)
- Создаём в нашей корневой папке(которую создали под сборку) папку `build`
- Заходим в неё и делаем `git clone https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja.git`
- Открываем Visual Studio. В ней: *Средства->Командная строка->Командная строка разработчика*. В командной строке прописываем путь до созданной папки `build` и прописываем `python configure.py --bootstrap`. Таким образом мы сконфигурировали `ninja`
- Находясь в нашей папке `build` в консоли прописываем следующее(**не забудьте поменять пути на свои**):

```
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=E:\OpenCV\build\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=E:\OpenCV\install -DANDROID_PROJECTS_BUILD_TYPE="ANT" -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_JAVA=ON -DBUILD_opencv_java=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB=ON -DBUILD_PYTHON:BOOL=OFF -DINSTALL_ANDROID_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DANDROID_EXAMPLES_WITH_LIBS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF -DWITH_OPENCL=ON -DANDROID_NDK_HOST_X64=ON  -DANDROID_NDK=C:/Users/volce/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r25b/   -DANDROID_SDK=C:/Users/volce/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/volce/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r25b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DANDROID_STL=c++_static -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON -DANDROID_ABI='arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86_64, x86' -DANDROID_NDK_HOST_X64=ON -DBUILD_opencv_python3:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_python2:BOOL=OFF  -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=E:/OpenCV/opencv_contrib/modules -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=25 -DANDROID_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=32 -DANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION=21  E:\OpenCV\opencv
```

- После выполнения прописываем `ninja -j8`
- Дождавшись выполнения предыдущей команды, пишем `ninja install`
- На выходе получаем OpenCV SDK под Android
- Как подключить OpenCV 4.6.0 в проект - [тык](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bR7lL886-uc)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ есть, но у меня другой путь (собирал при помощи Ninja + clang++ из тулчейна), вдруг кому пригодится :)

1. Скачиваем исходники с https://github.com/opencv/opencv, https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib
2. В проекте используется `Ninja` - он шел в комплекте с Qt, возможно, придется ставить отдельно
3. Собирать все придется при помощи специального toolchain'а из NDK, обычно лежит в папке `<NDK_PATH>/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake`
4. Создаем рядом папку, в которую будет собирать проект (запускаем из нее cmake для генерации проектных файлов):

   - при использовании CMake GUI не получилось указать ABI, только дефолтный, но если все же получится - то выбирать в качестве генератора `Ninja` - `Specify toolchain file for cross-compiling` и путь к тулчейну
   - Из консоли можно все сгенерировать одной командой (ниже)
5. Собираем проект командой `ninja -j8`
6. Устанавливаем командой `ninja install`

В команде ниже отключена большая часть библиотек, т.к. они не используются - соответственно, нужно внимательно проверить необходимые флаги (особенно -DBUILD_opencv_***). Еще команда очень длинная, так что аккуратнее с пробелами при копировании (еще ниже эта же команда в одну строчку под катом).

Здесь

- `D:\Development\opencv-4.5.0` - исходники opencv
- `D:\Development\opencv_contrib-4.5.0` - исходники opencv-contrib
- `D:\Development\opencv_contrib-4.5.0_android_sdk` - сюда собираем проект

Команда:

`cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/Alexey/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:/Development/opencv_contrib-4.5.0_android_sdk/install -DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_JAVA=ON -DBUILD_opencv_java=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB=ON -DBUILD_PYTHON:BOOL=OFF -DANDROID_EXAMPLES_WITH_LIBS:BOOL=OFF  -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF -DWITH_OPENCL=ON -DANDROID_NDK_HOST_X64=ON -DBUILD_PROTOBUF:BOOL=OFF -DWITH_PROTOBUF:BOOL=OFF -DWITH_ADE:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_dnn_objdetect=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_dnn_superres=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_dpm=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_datasets=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_optflow=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_stereo=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_tracking=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_ccalib=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_bioinspired=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_video=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_videostab=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_aruco=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_gapi=OFF -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DWITH_CAROTENE=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_surface_matching=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_saliency=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_rgbd=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_xphoto=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_plot=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_rapid=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_xfeatures2d=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_highgui=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_xobjdetect=OFF -DANDROID_NDK=C:/Users/Alexey/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393 -DANDROID_SDK=C:/Users/Alexey/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/Alexey/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DANDROID_STL=c++_static -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON -DANDROID_NDK_HOST_X64=ON  -DBUILD_opencv_python3:BOOL=OFF  -DBUILD_opencv_python2:BOOL=OFF -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=ON -DINSTALL_ANDROID_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=D:/Development/opencv_contrib-4.5.0/modules -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=OFF -DANDROID_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=32 -DANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION=24 -DBUILD_ZLIB=ON D:/Development/opencv-4.5.0`

Она же:

```
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/Alexey/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:/Development/opencv_contrib-4.5.0_android_sdk/install -DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_JAVA=ON -DBUILD_opencv_java=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB=ON -DBUILD_PYTHON:BOOL=OFF -DANDROID_EXAMPLES_WITH_LIBS:BOOL=OFF  -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF -DWITH_OPENCL=ON -DANDROID_NDK_HOST_X64=ON -DBUILD_PROTOBUF:BOOL=OFF -DWITH_PROTOBUF:BOOL=OFF -DWITH_ADE:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_dnn_objdetect=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_dnn_superres=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_dpm=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_datasets=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_optflow=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_stereo=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_tracking=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_ccalib=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_bioinspired=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_video=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_videostab=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_aruco=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_gapi=OFF -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DWITH_CAROTENE=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_surface_matching=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_saliency=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_rgbd=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_xphoto=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_plot=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_rapid=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_xfeatures2d=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_highgui=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_xobjdetect=OFF -DANDROID_NDK=C:/Users/Alexey/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393 -DANDROID_SDK=C:/Users/Alexey/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/Alexey/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DANDROID_STL=c++_static -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON -DANDROID_NDK_HOST_X64=ON  -DBUILD_opencv_python3:BOOL=OFF  -DBUILD_opencv_python2:BOOL=OFF -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=ON -DINSTALL_ANDROID_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=D:/Development/opencv_contrib-4.5.0/modules -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=OFF -DANDROID_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=32 -DANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION=24 -DBUILD_ZLIB=ON D:/Development/opencv-4.5.0
```

**Важно:**

- Для использования contrib нужно указать флаг `-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv_contrib>/modules`
- Сразу для всех ABI сгенерировать SDK не вышло, поэтому для каждого ABI (arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86_64, x86) придется все генерировать с нуля, т.е. несколько раз проворачивать всю процедуру с разными значениями `-DANDROID_ABI` и собирать полученные файлы в один общий SDK
- `libopencv_java4.so` генерируется в папке `jni` в корне только с флагом `-DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=ON`, но в зависимости от системы с этим флагом могут возникнуть проблемы на финальной сборке через `ninja` - у меня ругался на NDK, пришлось хитрить и то отключать, то включать обратно его (с `-DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=OFF` все собралось с ходу)
- Флаг `-DBUILD_ZLIB=ON` нужен, без него не линкуется на каком-то этапе

**P.S.**

Для универсальности также пришлось отредактировать финальный build.gradle, исправив блок `sourceSets`:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../../jni']
        java.srcDirs = ['src']  // TODO Use original files instead of copied into build directory
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['D:/Development/opencv-4.5.0/modules/java/android_sdk/android_gradle_lib/res']
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

на другие значения, которые используются в официальной сборке android-sdk:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['native/libs']
        java.srcDirs = ['java/src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['java/src']
        res.srcDirs = ['java/res']
        manifest.srcFile 'java/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```